# Cannot change MS SQL user password. Error 15010 Database does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a dev server with a bunch of old and new databases, I went to change the password for one of the SQL users but I got an error stating SQL could not find database files for TriModal. It was in the list of databases so I deleted it. Now I get this error.

```
Alter failed for Login 'TRNJApp'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

The database 'TriModal' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15010)
```

When I edit that user's User Mapings I get the message

```
One or more databases are inaccessible and will not be displayed in list.
```

TriModal does not appear in SELECT * FROM MASTER.SYS.DATABASES

Any ideas to rectify the problem?

## SQL Technical information for the Error

```
Alter failed for Login 'TRNJApp'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1750.9+((dac_inplace_upgrade).101209-1051+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Alter+Login&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login.Alter()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLoginData.LoginPrototype.ApplyGeneralChanges(Server server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLogin.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplFinish(StringCollection alterQuery, ScriptingOptions so)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImplWorker()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AlterImpl()

===================================

The database 'TriModal' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.  (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.3073&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15010&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: 192.168.1.27
Error Number: 15010
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
```

Comment: Have a look at the error log. The path is something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG".

Comment: The users' Default Database was blank but must have previously been TriModal. I set it to another database and everything is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments.

The users' Default Database was blank but must have previously been TriModal. I set it to another database and everything is working.